# Player offering other characters advice during combat

Tags: gm-techniques

How do you keep the one very experienced player from offering advice during  encounters, combat, etc.? Hes a great player, knows his stuff extremely well, but can't seem to keep his mouth shut, even when his character is not present for meetings, combat, etc.  I have found giving him gummy bears works to keep his mouth occupied, but would like other options.

Comment: What game/system are you playing?

Comment: This seems like a system-agnostic "problem player" kind of question, right?

Comment: @divibisan Could be for sure, but knowing the system could also potentially help focus the answers. For example, some systems are much more combat focused than others and that can have an effect on the weight that combat and combat-choices are intended to be given.

Comment: Possible duplicates/related questions: [How do I deal with a powergamer in a game full of beginners in a school club?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142952/39969), [How to stop one player taking control of the game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80594/39969), [How should I deal with a player telling other players when and what to roll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103465/39969)

Comment: Is this a problem to your other players, or does it just annoy you/the GM? I think you can expand on what is the actual problem is/why it is a problem. How is giving advice hurting the game for you (the group)?

Comment: @James Welcome to RPG.se! I put this question on hold because it looks like we have other questions that are asking the same thing and should give you an answer. If the linked questions don't answer what you want, please [edit] the details the make your question different into your question. Please let me know in the comments if you have any questions or confusion.